# Why aren't rational numbers implemented and stored as fractions with zero loss of information?

Tags: c++, floating-point, numbers

I know this is a bit hypothetical but I am wondering why no language I know does it.

For example, you want to store 1/3. Give the programmer an option to specify it as 1/3, and store 1 and 3. Something like

```
struct float {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};
```

Rational number arithmetic becomes really easy and considerably more accurate!

This would solve so many problems related to the precision and storage limitations of floating point numbers, and I dont see it introducing any new problems as well!

Hence my question: **Why aren't rational numbers implemented and stored as fractions with zero loss of information?**

---

As Joe asked, and others might also point out, I do not mean this to replace existing system, but to complement it.

Q: How do you store `pi`?

A: So many times, I am just storing `1/3` and not `pi`. `pi` can be stored the old way, and `1/3` in the new way.

Comment: @Joe: I thought this will come up. I do not mean this to replace existing system, but to complement it. So many times, I am just storing `1/3` and not pi. pi can be stored the old way, and `1/3` in the new way.

Comment: See [Boost.Rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/rational/).

Comment: The nice thing about OOP is that you **can** do this.

Comment: He probably wants support at the language level, or a library from the language itself?

Comment: This would not solve any problems related to storing precision and storage limitations of floating point numbers.   Because `int`s are a fixed number of bits, only certain fractions would be possible.  How would you represent 3.45x10^30?  How would you represent 1.23x10^-20?  All you are doing is changing what the limitations are.

Comment: A variety of languages support rational numbers at one level or another.

Comment: This is not really a (stackoverflow) question, in my opinion. I mean, there's no "absolute true" answer (unless Bjarne Stroustrup replies). If you ask me, it's something that you can implement if you want, but would bloat the language and would be confusing if it was there straight out of the box.

Comment: Languages do allow storing numbers as fractions.  You just have to do it yourself.  I would imagine this is because languages like C++ tend to expose scalars that correspond fairly closely to hardware (int, char, float, etc).  Processors don't have fractional ALUs, therefore every time you operated on this struct, a slow emulation of fractional math would have to occur.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: Yes, but the accuracy gain on the subset which can be represented is HUGE!

Comment: @Lazer This is not about the title. I'm just saying that nobody can tell you why it isn't implemented your way, we can just assume.

Comment: @Claudiu: And that I think, is a healthy SO discussion, as QA ofcourse.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: If you combine a big integer class with a rational class, your precision and range is limited only by your computer's resources.

Comment: @Lazer if you read the little blurb under the "not constructive" close vote, this question basically nails it.  I very seriously doubt anyone will be able to provide an answer that isn't just speculation.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, most modern Lisp dialects include 'true' rationals, as does Python.  (It seems to go along with built-in bignums.)

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Very true, but at serious performance cost.  As others have noted, you can certainly roll your own such class using some sort of BigNum, but your performance will be abysmal compared to `float`.  That's why this is not built into C++ as the standard way of doing floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @joe No computer can store pi precisely.  This is true both with standard C++ floats and what is being proposed here.  Irrational numbers cannot be precisely stored, period.

Comment: C++ includes a compile time rational arithmetic library. Values are represented by std::ratio. Arithmetic is done using meta functions such as std::ratio_multiply.

Comment: There is nothing special that would prevent exact rational datatypes. E.g. Haskell has them (in addition to big integers, normal fixed-width integers, and floating point numbers). Probably C++ lacks language-level support for (run-time) ratios because C doesn't have it either.

Comment: @bames53: C++ does _not_ include such feature. C++11, another _version_ of C++, does though.

Comment: @LuisMachuca The term "C++11" is not an official name for any ISO standard. The C++ programming language is defined by ISO/IEC 14882 and the most recent revision to that standard added compile-time rational arithmetic. I feel I'm perfectly justified on this basis to say that "C++ includes a compile time rational arithmetic library," without any qualification.

Comment: Standards are not retroactive, they are prescriptive legal documents. That said, yeah, the terms I used were quite confusing, should have used something like instead of "does". Perhaps "may", since C++ without rational arithmetic is still C++ (and legal).

Comment: Clojure by default uses rationals.

Comment: I think the question boils down to why there isn't hardware support for rational numbers. I think this is because any useful rational representation requires the computation of GCD (greates common denominator) and that is too much burden on hardware.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason they are not stored this way by default is that the range of valid values that can fit in a fixed set of bits is smaller.  Your `float` class can store numbers between 1/MAXINT and MAXINT (plus or minus).  A C/C++ `float` can represent numbers between 1E+37 and 1E-37 (plus or minus).  In other words, a standard `float` can represent values 26 orders of magnitude bigger and 26 orders of magnitude smaller then yours despite taking half the number of bits.  In general, it's more convenient to be able to represent very large and very small values than to be perfectly precise.  This is especially true since rounding tends to give us the right answers with small fractions like 1/3.  In g++, the following gives 1:

```
std::cout << ((1.0/3.0) * 3.0) << std::endl;
```

Remember that types in C++ have a fixed size in bits.  Thus a datatype in 32 bits has at most MAX_UINT values.  If you change the way it is represented, you're just changing which values can be precisely represented, not increasing them.  You can't cram more in, and thus can't be "more precise".  You trade being able to represent 1/3 precisely for not being able to represent other values precisely, like 5.4235E+25.

It is true that your `float` can represent values more precisely between 1E-9 and 1E+9 (assuming 32 bit ints) but at a cost of being completely unable to represent values outside of this range.  Worse, while the standard `float` always has 6 digits of precision, your `float` would have precision that varied depending on how close to zero the values were.  (And note that you are using twice the bits that `float` does.)

(I'm assuming 32 bit `int`s.  Same argument applies for 64 bit `int`s.)

**Edit**:  Also note that most data people use `float`s for is not precise anyway.  If you are reading data off of a sensor, you've already got imprecision, so being about to "perfectly" represent the value is pointless.  If you are using a `float` in any sort of computing context, it's not going to matter.  There is no point in perfectly describing '1/3' if your purpose is to display a bit of text 1/3rd of the way across the screen.

The only people who really need perfect precision are mathematicians, and they generally have software that gives them this.  Very few others need precision beyond what `double` gives.

Comment: You mention mathematicians as the only counter example, an important field that should never touch floating point numbers are financial applications (AFAIK they have their own rules for rounding that do not work with floating point).

Comment: Yes, but they only ever use integers.

Answer (score 11):

> Real number arithmetic becomes really easy and considerably more accurate!

No, it doesn't. The struct you describe only handles *rational* numbers, i.e. those that can be expressed as fractions. The set of real numbers includes both rational and irrational numbers. Most real-world calculations are done using real numbers, so you can't just limit yourself to the rationals and expect everything to be fine.

> I am wondering why no language I know does it.

Most of the languages that I can think of make it possible to do exactly what you describe. In C, you can create a struct that contains numerator and denominator, and you can define a bunch of functions that operate on such structs. C++ makes things a LOT easier by letting you define a class and operations on that class -- same idea, much nicer syntax, etc. In fact, different sets of numbers are often used as examples in OO languages: you might start by defining a Rational class, and then extend that to include Imaginary numbers, and so on.

I'd guess that the reason that there aren't more languages with built-in support for exact types probably has to do with the fact that processors don't directly support such operations. Modern processors include instructions that implement arithmetic operations for floating point types, so it's easy to include those in any language. Supporting exact types would mean building a math library into the language, and it's probably better on several levels to leave the math library out of the language and let those who need it build it into their software.

If you're going to go to all the trouble to produce exact results, you probably don't want to  limit yourself just to rationals, so the struct you give as an example isn't going to cut it. Being able to do exact calculations on rationals isn't very helpful if you fall back to inexact results the first time an irrational number shows up. Fortunately, there are sophisticated math systems out there. [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) is one well-known example.

Comment: I'd say this should be a comment and not an answer as with a minor, one-word modification to the OP it becomes a valid question again (that is: real number -> rational number).

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Expanded the answer. "Fixing" the question leads directly to the answer -- support for rationals isn't built in because rational numbers by themselves aren't all that useful in real-world calculation.

Comment: While the set of real numbers includes both rational and irrational numbers, standard datatypes can only handle rational numbers.  A `float` is internally two values, an integar numerator and a denominator that is a power of ten.  Thus it is always a rational.

Comment: @StevenBurnap That's certainly true, but we think of floats as limited-precision representations of reals. The *representation* is rational but the number being represented may not be.

Comment: Same could be said for the proposal, though.  355/113 is a rational approximation of pi as is 31415926/10000000.  Both are "limited-precision representations of reals".

Comment: Except that we already *have* one such representation, and the OP's motivation is the opposite of limited precision reals: *"Why aren't rational numbers implemented and stored as fractions with **zero loss** of information?"*

Comment: I know this an old answer, but still, you are applying circular logic here. Your argument against using rationals is that we already have a system using rationals pretending to cover all reals. "Limited-precision reals" are just rational numbers, nothing else. No actual (non-symbolic) computation has ever been done with irrational numbers. You can still approximate reals with a system that allows computions on rationals with zero information loss.

Comment: @Martin I fully understand that we already use rational numbers to represent reals. My point above (IIRC) was that storing those rationals as {numerator,denominator} pairs doesn't give *more* accuracy (in general) than floating point. OP is of course correct that *some* calculations could be done exactly, but wrong in the assertion that it would "solve so many problems related to the precision and storage limitations of floating point numbers". Storing fractions isn't necessarily worse, but it's not appreciably better. I don't think that argument is circular at all.

Answer (score 8):

C++ at least includes a compile time rational arithmetic library. Here's an example:

```
#include <ratio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using a = std::ratio<3,5>;
    using b = std::ratio<7,6>;

    using c = std::ratio_multiply<a,b>::type;

    std::cout << c::num << '/' << c::den << '\n'; // prints 7/10
}
```

Here we multiply 3/5 by 7/6 and get 7/10.

Answer (score 6):

Strap on your helmets, because we're about to get theoretical up in here.

Any math undergrad could give you an elevator explanation of Cantor's proof of the uncountable cardinality of the real numbers. For a longer explanation, go [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

But as Caleb pointed out, the real number field contains both rational and irrational numbers. This means that some subset of the real number field will never be representable as a numerator/denominator pair. How big is this subset? As it turns out, *most* real numbers are irrational, because the set of rationals is countable.

Here's the punchline: Storing numbers in this way would be very silly because *most* outputs of real-valued functions cannot be stored as a numerator and a denominator.

This may seem hard to believe, but think about common transcendental functions, e.g. sin, cos, log. Most outputs of these functions aren't rational, and the guys who wrote IEEE 754 and other early FP stuff knew this. They figured that dealing with a small amount of error in exchange for the possibility of representing (with some truncation) a much larger portion of the real number field was a good design tradeoff.

Comment: The question is about **rational** number. While I agree on the argument about real number, your answer is a bit off-topic.

Comment: Addendum: Also consider that many commonly-used transcendental functions are implemented using interpolation on lookup tables or using a finite sequence approximation, which means that error exists in the outputs anyway.

Comment: Since irrational numbers can't be represented using a finite decimal (or binary) representation ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Decimal_expansions)), actually a (IEEE 754) `float` can represent no irrational number.

Comment: @nhatdh I disagree, the OP asked why languages don't have built-in support for rational types. My answer is pretty clearly on-topic.

Comment: @Florian No, you're absolutely right. That's why there is truncation and error allowed with IEEE 754 numbers.

Comment: @pg1989: Is your argument "The support is not there because the application is not wide enough"?

Comment: Partially, yeah. As I said before, some very basic theoretical arguments show that it's a classic example of a very poor engineering decision, namely because it is a large investment of time and energy for a minute gain in narrow use cases.

Comment: Every number representable in IEEE 754 is a rational number...

Comment: Technically yes. Florian made the same argument 4 comments up, see my response to him.

Comment: Your punchline can be modified to apply to IEEE 754 values. "Storing numbers in this way would be very silly because most outputs of real-valued functions cannot be stored as an exponent and a finite precision fraction." I believe this shows that your conclusion does not follow from the proposition. Using a numerator/denominator pair may be silly, but not for this reason.

Comment: Did you read my response to your last comment? Florian brought up the same point earlier in the comments thread, read my response to him.

Comment: @pg1989 If we were to use numerator/denominator pairs instead of IEEE 754, guess how we'd approximate the unrepresentable real numbers. There is nothing about your argument against numerator/denominator pairs that does not apply equally well to IEEE 754. Your implication that IEEE 754 can represent "a much larger portion of the real number field"  is false. Any real number you want to approximate with IEEE 754 can also be approximated with numerator/denominator pairs with exactly the same truncation or error.

Answer (score 5):

Many CPUs have special treatment for floating points ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit)) and the `float` data type in the language ensures programs can utilize the FPU in an easy way. On the other hand I don't know of any CPU which can handle Fractions with special assembler instructions so fractions can easily and efficiently be implemented inside a library and don't have to be a language feature. If you want to use fractions in C++, you can use [Boost.Rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit).

The Reason why modern CPUs implement floating point arithmetic instead of handling fractions is that floating points can be implemented much more easily. To implement the basic `float` operations you basically need to be able to add, subtract multiply and divide integers and do some bit shifting. To compare to fractions on the other hand you need to find the greatest common divisor of two ints, which is much harder to implement in hardware.

Comment: Isn't this argument circular? I think the OP was asking about the *original* design decisions related to FP. Modern CPUs have FP instructions because of the prevalence of floating point numbers.

Comment: Lack of hardware support is definitely a major reason, but I'd say it likely goes much farther than that.  vector's aren't supported by hardware, yet C++ includes those.  There's a relatively low demand for a 'fraction' class, and a basic one is extremely easy to make.  I would imagine that definitely factors in as well.

Comment: On the other hand I think there are better ways to store floats than [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard), but since it has been used since many years and is implemented in most modern CPUs it is hard to replace it with a different standard.

Comment: @Corbin I think the reason not to include it in the standard is because there was no proposal yet. Classes like `std::enable_if` are really easy to implement, too, but are in the standard anyway.

Comment: @FlorianSowade "because there was no proposal yet" That falls under the reason of lack of demand. :)

Comment: There is a proposal: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3363.html

Comment: @pg1989 thanks for the comment - tried to add this in the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to many of the answers you've gotten, your idea is good for many kinds of problems.  Especially [problems like this one in which you know that there will be a lot of cancelling, and want an exact answer.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27884/odds-of-x-occurrences-in-a-row-given-y-trials-a-coin-flip-problem/28001#28001)  For this reason, Python has the `fractions` module, and as @bames53 points out, C++ has `<ratio>`.

Answer (score 2):

> “Hence my question: Why aren't rational numbers implemented and stored as fractions with zero loss of information?”

The C++ standard library lacks many practically necessary types that other languages and libraries offer. The Boost library already offers a [rational number implementation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1977.html). And it [appears](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/04/192500.php) that it may shortly also offer the [proposed decimal types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1977.html), e.g. for handling currency amounts.

As to why those types are lacking, the C++ standard library generally just provides bare bones general building blocks, not the more practically useful things that one would build with those blocks. I.e. it's minimalistic. The Boost library is just a tad less minimalistic, and then e.g. the Poco library is more like other languages’ more functionally rich standard libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons:
- No support from common architecture. This is understandable, since fraction must always comes with simplification. This is not trivial to be implemented at hardware level, or rather, it will be an instruction without much application.
- Cannot handle very big or very small numbers. Or BigInteger must involve. And for very big or very small numbers, we usually don't need most of the precision provided.
- If this is a type supported at the language level, it must support conversion with other numeric types. It must decide when to return floating type if the internal representation has fixed precision (in case of multiplication).

In a language, the decision to support something is usually decided by its application (or the rationale of the language). If the application is small, it has less chance to be supported.